# When turning on event scheduler error shows #1408 - Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I am using Linux Pop!_OS 20.10 and xampp. When I try to turn on the event scheduler in phpmyadmin an error shows up

```
#1408 - Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
```

I have tried different solutions but nothing helped.

Tried to add event_scheduler=ON in my.cnf file but still, nothing is happening

Tried to turn it on by setting it from SQL but still threw the same error

Any ideas will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: PHP is a majority of the time unrelated to `phpmyadmin`. This is a `mysql` or `phpmyadmin` issue.  PHP is just the language used to run the interface (e.g. HTML and CSS are just as relevant).

Comment: And if you are using XAMPP it is more likely you are actually using `mariaDB`

Comment: Yup, I know any Ideas? I tried even reinstalling xampp server and downloading new updates but nothing helps.

Comment: What should I try!

Comment: Did you check that the `events` table set exists

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I have used this query `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler';` and it showed this `event_scheduler OFF` in a table so I think they are existing.